# In makefile, How to replace the directory aaa/bbb/ccc/ with ../../../

Tags: makefile

In my Makefile, I know the path of directory, and need to rollback of directory.

Here is my work case:
I am writing the Android makefile, following is some code:

```
LOCAL_PATH :=$(call my-dir)  #this will get the path that Android.mk locate.
...
LOCAL_MODULE := mymod
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := /tmp/mymod.ko
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
.....
```

According to Android prebuild system(which implemented in build/core/prebuild.mk), this will copy the $(LOCAL_PATH)/tmp/mymod.ko to the destination($(LOCAL_PATH)added by prebuid.mk), but I want to locate the mymod.ko just to /tmp, so I have to add some ../../../ to my LOCAL_SRC_FILES, that I can remove the $(LOCAL_PATH).

that is, I need replace $(LOCAL_PATH) to some ../../..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
empty   :=
spaces  := $(empty) $(empty)
to-root  = $(subst $(space),/,$(patsubst %,..,$(subst /,$(space),$1)))

# Test
$(info aaa/bbb/ccc -> $(call to-root,aaa/bbb/ccc))
```

This will break if one of the path components contains a space, but `make` cannot handle those very well anyway.